# ¿Por qué se detiene mi aplicación al elegir opción en Spinner?

Tags: java, android, adapter

Tengo un `Spinner` que funciona así, selecciono una opción y manda el texto a `editTextZodiaco`, los textos se muestran correctamente en mi `Spinner`, pero cuando selecciono una opción para que lo mande a `editTextZodiaco` la aplicación se detiene, el `logcat` me marca lo siguiente:

> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=4

`clase`

```
       String[] zodiaco = {};
    int flags[] = {R.drawable.icon_zod_elig, R.drawable.icon_zod_no, R.drawable.icon_zod_acuario, R.drawable.icon_zod_piscis, R.drawable.icon_zod_aries, R.drawable.icon_zod_tauro, R.drawable.icon_zod_geminis, R.drawable.icon_zod_cancer, R.drawable.icon_zod_leo, R.drawable.icon_zod_virgo, R.drawable.icon_zod_libra, R.drawable.icon_zod_escorpio, R.drawable.icon_zod_sagitario, R.drawable.icon_zod_capricornio};

 @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        if(position == 1){
            editTextZodiaco.setText(" ");
        }else if(position !=0){
            String description = zodiaco[position];
            editTextZodiaco.setText(description.split(" ")[0]);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }

    CustomAdapter customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(getApplicationContext(), flags, zodiaco);
        spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        spin.setAdapter(customAdapter);
```

`CustomAdapter`:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    Context context;
    int flags[];
    String[] titulo_zodiaco;
    LayoutInflater inflter;

    public CustomAdapter(Context applicationContext, int[] flags, String[] titulo_zodiaco) {
        this.context = applicationContext;
        this.flags = flags;
        this.titulo_zodiaco = titulo_zodiaco;
        inflter = (LayoutInflater.from(applicationContext));
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return flags.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        view = inflter.inflate(R.layout.custom_spinner_items, null);
        ImageView icon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imagenspinner);
        TextView names = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textspinner);

//////// carga los textos de array

        String[] titulo_zodiaco = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.titulos_zodiaco);

        icon.setImageResource(flags[i]);
        names.setText(titulo_zodiaco[i]);
        return view;
    }
}
```

`array`:

```
  <array name="titulos_zodiaco">
        <item>Elige un Zodiaco</item>
        <item>No quiero ninguno</item>
        <item>Acuario (Ene. 20 - Feb. 18)</item>
        <item>Piscis (Feb. 19 - Marzo 20)</item>
        <item>Aries (Marzo 31 - Abril 19)</item>
        <item>Tauro (Abril 20 - Mayo 20)</item>
        <item>Géminis (Mayo 21 - Junio 20)</item>
        <item>Cáncer (Junio 21 - Julio 22)</item>
        <item>Leo (Julio 23 - Agosto 22)</item>
        <item>Virgo (Agosto 23 - Sep. 22)</item>
        <item>Libra (Sep. 23 - Oct. 22)</item>
        <item>Escorpio (Oct. 23 - Nov. 21)</item>
        <item>Sagitario (Nov. 22 - Dic. 21)</item>
        <item>Capricornio (Dic. 22 - Ene. 19)</item>
    </array>
```

**EDITO2**: @Jorgesys

`Clase`

```
public class SeccionActivity extends Activity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

    private TextView editTextZodiaco;

    String[] zodiaco = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.titulos_zodiaco);
    int flags[] = {R.drawable.icon_zod_elig, R.drawable.icon_zod_no, R.drawable.icon_zod_acuario, R.drawable.icon_zod_piscis, R.drawable.icon_zod_aries, R.drawable.icon_zod_tauro, R.drawable.icon_zod_geminis, R.drawable.icon_zod_cancer, R.drawable.icon_zod_leo, R.drawable.icon_zod_virgo, R.drawable.icon_zod_libra, R.drawable.icon_zod_escorpio, R.drawable.icon_zod_sagitario, R.drawable.icon_zod_capricornio};

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        if (position == 1) {
            editTextZodiaco.setText(" ");
        } else if (position != 0) {
            String description = zodiaco[position];
            editTextZodiaco.setText(description.split(" ")[0]);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activit_seccion);

        editTextZodiaco = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editTextZodiaco);
        Spinner spin = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerzodiaco);


        CustomAdapter customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(getApplicationContext(), flags, zodiaco);
        spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        spin.setAdapter(customAdapter);
    }
}
```

Comment: El error es muy explicito. `Out of Bounds` indica que te sales del limite del elemento. Tiene una longitud de 0 elementos y accedes al indice 4 que no existe.

Comment: Imagino que es porque busca los textos en `String[] zodiaco = {};` y debería buscarlos en `String[] titulo_zodiaco = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.titulos_zodiaco);` como le marco en el `CustomAdapter` @lois6b

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu array esta vacio:

```
 String[] zodiaco = {};
```

y tratas de obtener un elemento:

```
 String description = zodiaco[position];
```

---

Elimina la obtención de los datos del array dentro de `getView()`, lo correcto es que el `Adapter` al ser instanciado tenga los datos necesarios.

```
   //Obtiene datos del array. 
   //String[] zodiaco = {};
    String[] zodiaco = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.titulos_zodiaco);
   //Configura el Adapter.
   CustomAdapter customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(getApplicationContext(), flags, zodiaco);
```

En tu código realizarías el siguiente cambio:

```
public class SeccionActivity extends Activity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

    private TextView editTextZodiaco;
    private String[] zodiaco; //*** ᕦ /͠- ‿ ͝-\ ᕥ
    private Spinner spin;
    //String[] zodiaco = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.titulos_zodiaco);
    int flags[] = {R.drawable.icon_zod_elig, R.drawable.icon_zod_no, R.drawable.icon_zod_acuario, R.drawable.icon_zod_piscis, R.drawable.icon_zod_aries, R.drawable.icon_zod_tauro, R.drawable.icon_zod_geminis, R.drawable.icon_zod_cancer, R.drawable.icon_zod_leo, R.drawable.icon_zod_virgo, R.drawable.icon_zod_libra, R.drawable.icon_zod_escorpio, R.drawable.icon_zod_sagitario, R.drawable.icon_zod_capricornio};

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        if (position == 1) {
            editTextZodiaco.setText(" ");
        } else if (position != 0) {
            String description = zodiaco[position];
            editTextZodiaco.setText(description.split(" ")[0]);
        }
        //Se mueve a la posición seleccionada.
        spin.setSelection(position); 
    }


    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activit_seccion);

        editTextZodiaco = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editTextZodiaco);
        spin = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerzodiaco);

        zodiaco = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.titulos_zodiaco); //***ᕦ /͠- ‿ ͝-\ ᕥ

        CustomAdapter customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(getApplicationContext(), flags, zodiaco);
        spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        spin.setAdapter(customAdapter);
    }
}
```

Comment: Por que quiero que los obtenga de aquí `(R.array.titulos_zodiaco)` ya que están ahí los titulos, cómo puedo hacerlo? @Jorgesys

Comment: Elimina esta línea dentro de getView() :  String[] titulo_zodiaco = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.titulos_zodiaco);
 no es necesaria ni correcta ahí, revisa mi actualización, es correcto tu código solo necesita un pequeño cambio.

Comment: ahhh si estas en MainActivity obviamente no necesitas "context".

Comment: Estoy en `CrearPersonaActivity` , se me cierra cuando intento abrir la clase, ahí es donde tengo el `Spinner` añado el nuevo `logcat` a la pregunta @Jorgesys

Comment: Podrías agregar la clase: CrearPersonaActivity,  es simplemente el contexto, si usas la variable tiene valor null, agrega la clase y te comento que realizar.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54087/discussion-between-jorgesys-and-usernameyo).

Comment: Funciona, pero tengo un problema que no tenía antes, cuando selecciono una opción en mi `Spinner` aunque envía bien el texto a `editTextZodiaco` no se marca en el `Spinner` lo que acabo de seleccionar, antes no pasaba, es con el cambio de código que me comentas, a qué se debe? Gracias @Jorgesys

Comment: No se marca, te refieres a que cambia la opción?

Comment: Me parece que esto debio suceder siempre. ya que se debe configurar el adapter antes de configurar el listener, pero en este caso tu Clase extiende de OnItemSelectedListener.  Agrega : spin.setSelection(i); ve la respuesta.

Comment: Te puedo confirmar que antes si funcionaba, lo he vuelto a probar y antes si funciona, con lo que me comentas me marca Android Studio, "error: cannot find symbol variable i" @Jorgesys

Comment: Tal vez porque la forma de incializar el Adapter era diferente, el adapter tenia los datos del array. Bueno cambia a "position" y no "i"   spin.setSelection(position); eso fue equivocación mía =P

Comment: Solucionado! Muchas gracias como siempre @Jorgesys !